# Find an homography that transform the circumference $\mathopen|z\mathclose|=2$ in $\mathopen|z+1\mathclose| = 1$ and -2 to 0 and 0 to i.

Tags: complex-analysis

I started with the function f(z) = $\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$. Then, from f(-2)=0 and f(0)=i and obtained b=2a and d=-2ai. After that, i took a $z\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $\mathopen|z\mathclose|=2$ and tried to find a and c such that $\mathopen|f(z) + 1\mathclose|=1$. Tried lots of stuff, but couldn't find something concrete. In general, my approach was to use the properties $\mathopen|z+w\mathclose|^2=\mathopen|z\mathclose|^2 + \mathopen|w\mathclose|^2 + 2Re(z\overline{w})$. Tried choosing some z such $\mathopen|z\mathclose|=2$, but i couldn't clear a and c.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try starting with $|z||f(z)+1|=2$ with some $z$ ? $z=2$ for instance ?

Comment: I didn't, and i don't quite get how that can make things easier. I already know that $|z|$ = 2, so my first reflex is to divide by 2 both sides getting the same. I'll give it a try as soon as i can anyways, in case there is something i'm not seeing.